# How to replace ↵ to \n

Tags: javascript

I want to replace the string ↵ to \n.

```js
let test = 'te↵s↵t'
test = test.replace(/&#8629;/g, '\n')
console.log(test)
```

I tried to use replace using regex.
I want to get result `te\ns\nt`

How can I replace string?

Comment: What's wrong with `test.replace(/↵/g, '\n')`?

Comment: `a = test.replace(/↵/g, '\\n')`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you **really** want to get string `te\ns\nt`, try this code :

```js
let test = 'te↵s↵t'
test = test.replace(/↵/g, '\\n')
console.log(test)
```

Answer (score 2):

As it stands, your expression is trying to match the literal string `&#8629;`.

To make it work, you can just replace the literal character `↵`, or if you want to specify an escape sequence, use the Unicode escape sequence for `↵` ([`\u21b5`](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+21B5)):

```js
let test = 'te↵s↵t';
test = test.replace(/↵/g, '\n');

console.log(test);
```

```js
let test = 'te↵s↵t';
test = test.replace(/\u21b5/g, '\n');

console.log(test);
```

If you want to replace with the literal `\n` instead of a newline, your replacement sequence needs to be `\\n` instead of `\n`.

Answer (score 2):

`test.replace(/↵/g, '\n')` or `test.replace(/\u21b5/g, '\n')` should both work. `&#8629;` is an HTML escape; you do not have a HTML string.